# Turn of Warnings in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

Everyone know this little warnings in Flash Builder when working with Flex, something like:

```
warning: unable to bind to property 'blabla' on class 'BlaBla'
```

It´s very kind of the Flash Builder to warn me on that, but I would like to turn this off :)

I already tried using

```
-show-binding-warnings=false
```

as additional compiler argument, but this does not seem to be working. 
Has anyone out there managed to turn this off in Flash Builder 4.7 using Apache Flex ?

Comment: I'm really curious why you'd want to do this. I'm not saying this should be closed or nobody should answer, but I just can't think why you wouldn't want them.

Comment: Simply because it´s annoying. I got TONS of those warnings with the addition "(class is not an IEventDispatcher)". But since all classes, which are causing those warnings inherit from EventDispatcher, I am pretty sure, this is a bug :)

Comment: Show us one of the classes, something is most likely not set as `[Bindable]` properly even if the class extends EventDispatcher :).

Comment: Flex is warning you because it has been told to bind a property that is not bindable. Don't put lipstick on a pig, just fix your warnings.

Comment: What makes me wonder about this "lipstick thing" and "not bindable" is: If it´s not bindable, why does the binding work?

Answer (score 0):

**If you're having a Flash project go to:**

Project>Properties>ActionScript Compiler
There just tick off the `Enable warnings` checkbox.

**If you're using Flex instead of pure AS3 go to:**

Project>Properties>ActionScript Compiler>Flex Compiler
And tick off the `Enable warnings` checkbox.

Comment: It doesn't really makes sense, since it worked fine for me on few different versions of Flash Builder (4.6 and 4.7). It could be some bug... or you have some settings of your project that overrides the GUI settings.
Did you try to tick off the Strict Mode in the same window? Although it shouldn't be different.